# Typescript how to define callback function?

Tags: typescript

I have function like this:

```
 .add({a: 1, b: 2}, function (msg, reply) {
    reply({z: msg.z})
  })
```

It tried something like this:

```
interface SenecaMethods {
    add: (patern: object, HERE SHOULD BE CALLBACK) => object;
}
```

How can define type for this?

Answer (score 0):

Same way you defined the type for `add` - function types look the same for callbacks as they do for any other kind of function. Just put it inside the brackets:

```
interface SenecaMethods {
    // Obviously you should replace the 'any's with your actual types!
    add: (patern: object, cb: (msg: any, reply: any) => any) => object;
}
```

Comment: The `reply` param is also a function